# Grant permissions using rsync

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, rsync

I want to use `rsync` (as a user) from "me" on a local computer to "another" user on a distant computer. However, I also want "another" user (on the distant computer) to own the files and to be able to use them exactly as "me" (on the local computer).

I believe I should play with the options: `-p` (preserve permissions), `-g` (preserve groups) and `-o` (preserve ownership), but I'm not sure of the exact effect of those. Which one(s) shall I use?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use "-a", which copies the files in "archive mode" (keeping permissions, links etc.).

If you use ssh as the shell, then the ownership etc. will happen by default:

```
rsync -a -e "ssh -l remote_user" hostname:remote_folder/ local_folder
```

You need to do this two ways, to copy local files to remote and vice verse.

(Personally, I'm not quite happy using rsync to do this, since there can be problems if both people have edited a file etc. I'm sure there are ways around this, but I've taken to using a subversion repository and an automated script to synchronise files.)